# Drop row in a for loop Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a (very large) pandas dataframe like the following:

| Sequence |
| --- |
| AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA |
| AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC |
| AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAG |
| AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAT |
| AAAACAGAAGGTGTCCCAATACTAT |
| AAAACAGATCTCGGCAGATTGGATG |
| AAAACAGATCTCGGTAGACTGGACG |

And I want to remove rows where the percentage of A is greater than 0.80.
Here is my code:

```
sequences = file[['Sequence']]

seq_A = 'A' * 25

for row in range(len(file)):
    par1 =  file.iloc[row,0]
    
    # compare sequence with homopolymer and check ratio of match
    ratioA = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, par1, seq_A).ratio()
        
    if ratioA >= 0.80:
        sequences.drop(row, axis=0, inplace=True)
        # lista.append(row)
```

But when I check the number of rows with such features with a new list in which I have inserted the indices (without deleting rows), the number of indices does not match the number of deleted rows.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should generally avoid loops with pandas. Here is how you can do it:

```py
df.loc[df['Sequence'].str.count('A') / df['Sequence'].str.len() <= 0.8]
```

produces:

```py
                    Sequence
4  AAAACAGAAGGTGTCCCAATACTAT
5  AAAACAGATCTCGGCAGATTGGATG
6  AAAACAGATCTCGGTAGACTGGACG
```

Comment: May I do it also with two letters of comparison? Like sequences.loc[sequences['Sequence'].str.count('A') / sequences['Sequence'].str.len() <= 0.8 and sequences['Sequence'].str.count('T') / sequences['Sequence'].str.len() <= 0.8] ?

Comment: @DeniseLavezzari yes, just use `&` instead of `and`, and wrap each of your conditions in braces like this: `( ) & ( )`. And for better optimization, you can save the lengths mask to a variable, and use this variable instead of calculating it again and again: `lengths = sequences['Sequence'].str.len()`, and then use `... / lengths <= 0.8 ...`

Comment: (correction: `lengths` is not a mask, but the numbers: the lengths of each string)